# How does the Pratt & Whitney Canada PT6 differ from other turboprop engines?

Tags: turboprop

As far as I know, all turboprop engines have mechanical continuity between the engine and the propeller except for the Pratt & Whitney Canada PT6 family of engines. What is the correct term for the setup the PT6 uses to power the propellor and how does the PT6's design differ from other turboprop engines?

Comment: I can't actually find the term “direct drive” used with turbo**prop** engine anywhere, only with turbo**shaft**. Also as far as I can tell, the layout of PT6 is pretty typical (separate gas generator turbine and free power turbine, reverse flow so the shaft from the free power turbine does not need to go through or around the engine).

Comment: Good call. I'll edit "direct drive" out.

Comment: That does not necessarily mean the term would be incorrect. Just that it is not common.

Comment: After thinking about it, it might be considered incorrect. When the term direct drive is used with piston engines the propeller is attached directly to the flywheel. No turboprop engine can work without a reduction gear. Even if there's mechanical continuity it's not really direct drive.

Comment: I don't think there is any difference in mechanical continuity. Some early engines might have had the propeller on the same shaft as compressor, but all the modern ones use free power turbine where the low pressure turbine only drives the propeller and high pressure turbine (or high and intermediate pressure turbines) drive the compressor. So turning the propeller _won't_ turn the compressor and starter won't turn the propeller.

Comment: @JanHudec A quick google seach located several references to "direct drive" turboprops such as [this one](http://www.langleyflyingschool.com/Pages/CPGS%203%20Airframes,%20Engines%20and%20Systems,%20Part%202.html). They all use the term to refer to a single shaft engine as opposed to a "free turbine." [This pdf](http://www.cast-safety.org/pdf/2_engine_types.pdf) actually uses "direct drive" to refer to the fuel pump system.

Comment: @JanHudec I'm not sure if I agree with everything you said there based on what I understand about turboprop engines, but I do think removing the "direct drive" reference had an overall positive impact on the question.

Comment: @TomMcW, that makes sense. But according to that definition PT6 is not unusual, because most turboprops have free power turbine.

Comment: there is no direct drive there is gear box to the propeller but i think there will be some torque issues i dont know how thy solve that detrimental problem

Answer (score 7):

### Split Shaft

Several turboprop engines, including the PT6 turboprop engine, use an [epicyclic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epicyclic_gearing) gearbox only, many other turboprop engines use a multishaft [gearbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gearbox). The latter usually results in the propeller axis being offset from the turbine axis.

In common with some other engines, the PT6 turbine is also reversed. This facilitates the **split-shaft** arrangement where the engine and propeller are driven by separate (but in-line) shafts, each connected to their own turbine wheel.

---

### PT6

[image]
<sup>Image: P&W</sup>

[image]
<sup>Image:[12Charlie](http://12charlie.com/)</sup>

### A contrasting and common design

[image]
<sup>Image:[12Charlie](http://12charlie.com/)</sup>

Comment: I'm trying to understand how any turboprop/shaft _with a gearbox_ can be described as "direct drive". Any help?

Comment: @egid: I imagine it means that there is a continuous metallic contact through the power train from compressor to propellor. This is not the case in the PT6.

Comment: Ah, I see. That would make some sense.

Comment: I think "direct drive" was the wrong term to use here. I edited it out of my original question.

Comment: I don't think the layout is truly specific to PT6. Reverse flow is used in the other small turboprop engines too, at least in Allison 250/RR M250 and Walter M601. The layout of Allison 250 is rather complicated with two-shaft gearbox and compressor in the front, but at least the Walter M601 seems to have the same layout as PT6 with split shaft and in-line planetary gearbox. The layout does not appear in large engines, probably because turning larger air mass flow is no longer practical.

Comment: @Jan, Thanks, I'll update the answer to include that point.

Comment: @Jan: Often, the large engines borrow their hot section from turbojets or turbofans. Also, their diameter would grow too big for a clean aerodynamic design.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is quite simple , with the Pratt and Whitney design there is no direct mechanical link between the turbine compressor and hot section to the propeller gearbox reduction drive . With  the Allison design were you to turn the propeller by hand all the turbine parts will move all the way back to the inlet compressor . There is a direct mechanical link all the way through

Answer (score -1):

As described above, it's a split shaft turboprop engine.  The design isn't unique to the PT-6 (T-74) but the PT-6 variants are by far the most ubiquitous split shaft turboprops on the market today.